# Eclipse Error on Refresh Workspace

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have a little problem with Eclipse, which is driving me insane.
i cannot figure out why, but Eclipse won't refresh any of my projects. it always reports following error:

An internal error occurred during: "Refreshing workspace".
java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Lorg.eclipse.core.resources.FileInfoMatcherDescription;

Well ... google did not helped so far. I tried to close all my projecst and open them again. I also deleted my whole workspace and set up a new Eclipse. It helped for about 2 hours.

has anyone occured the same problem?

Greetings,
Stef

Comment: Java version? Eclipse version?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149 

and JDK 1.6.29

Answer (score 1):

Look at your Eclipse log file (/.metadata/.log) to get the full stack trace and see if that helps you (it probably won't). But then take it and file a bug at eclipse.org, someone will look at it and might have a workaround or something.